# Tabela exibindo mais linhas do que deveriam

Tags: php, mysql, php-7

Estou criando uma tabela para exibir os horários das aulas de uma escola em php, mas quando a exibição é feita, o numero de linhas da tabela é igual ao numero de linhas no banco, mas em apenas uma delas o registro correto aparece. Também notei que a posição da informação é a mesma posição do banco.
Exemplo: Eu tenho três registros em meu banco de dados. Pedro, Gabriel e John.

John tem aula às 20:00.
Gabriel tem aula às 18:00.
Pedro tem aula às 09:00.
(Esta é a ordem do cadastro no banco de dados)

A tabela do banco de dados irá exibir todos os horários 3 vezes, pois existem 3 registros e no registro do Pedro ele irá aparecer na terceira linha correspondente a hora dele.

Outro detalhe é que a tabela está duplicada. Vai de 09:00 ate 22:00 duas vezes.

[image: registro 1]
[image: registro 2]

```
 <?php
    include("pages/topo.php");
    include("inc/banco.php");
?>

    <?php
    
      $queryDados = "SELECT id, nome, hora_aula FROM alunos ";
      $resultDados = mysqli_query($con, $queryDados);
      

    ?>
            <div id="layoutSidenav_content">
                <main>
                    <div class="container-fluid px-4">
                        <h1 class="mt-4">Aulas</h1>
                        <ol class="breadcrumb mb-4">
                            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Quadro de Aulas</li>
                        </ol>
                        
              
                    <div class="card mb-4">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <i class="fas fa-table me-1"></i>
                            <?php echo date("d/m/Y") . "<br>";?>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <table id="datatablesSimple">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                           <th width="0.5%">Hora</th>
                                           <th width="15%">Sala 1</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                   <tbody>
                                   <?php
                                 
                                       while($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDados))
                                        {                                   

                                    ?>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>09:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "09:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>10:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "10:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                        <td>11:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "11:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                        <td>12:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "12:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                        <td>13:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "13:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                        <td>14:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "14:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                        <td>15:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "15:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                         <tr>
                                        <td>16:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "16:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>17:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "17:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>18:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "18:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>19:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "19:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>20:00</td>
                                            <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "20:00")
                                                {
                                                  echo "<td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>\n";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td>21:00</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <?php if ($dados["hora_aula"] == "21:00")
                                                    {
                                                      echo $dados["nome"];
                                                    }
                                                ?>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        
                                   }
                                    ?> 
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
<?php
    include("pages/footer.php");
?>

<?php
```

Comment: Execute a consulta `SELECT id, nome, hora_aula FROM alunos` diretamente no Workbench e poste o resultado.

Comment: Códigos muito específicos ou individuais não atendem bem ao objetivo do site. Para prosseguir com a postagem aberta é importante [edit] e trocar o código por um [mcve] do problema, de forma que este seja fácil de localizar até por um leigo e as respostas possam servir de referência para futuros visitantes. Mais detalhes em [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e no [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que toda a sua `<tbody>` está dentro do looping `while`. Logo, tudo será repetido até que todos os registros sejam contemplados.

Se você quer exibir apenas os resultados, basta fazer isso:

```
<?php 
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDados)) {
    echo 
    "<tr>
    <td>".$dados["hora_aula"]."</td>
    <td>".$dados["nome"]."</td>
    </tr>";
}  
?>
```

Porém, parece que você também quer mostrar os horários vazios, então você pode tratar o resultados do banco de dados antes de exibi-los, assim:

```
<?php 
$dadosFinais = [];
for ($i=8; $i < 21; $i++) { 
    $dadosFinais[($i<10?"0":"").$i.":00"] = "";
}
while($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultDados)) {
    $dadosFinais[$dados["hora_aula"]] = $dados["nome"];
}  

foreach ($dadosFinais as $hora => $nome) {
    echo 
    "<tr>
    <td>".$hora."</td>
    <td>".$nome."</td>
    </tr>";
}
?>
```

Você também consegue gerar os resultados dos horários vazios direto pela consulta no banco de dados.

Comment: Deu certinho. Obrigado amigo